Best type of join to use
I'm having an issue with the below query with either filtering out rows that are needed, or including extra rows that aren't desired (Depending on whether or not I use the OR condition below). I am LEFT OUTER JOINing PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES as their are some cases where there are some rows in PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES that are not in PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL.
The issue is in the final WHERE clause where I only return rows from PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN with a LAST_UPDATE_DATE within the last two days, OR where the LAST_UPDATE_DATE from PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES is within the last two days. If I don't use the 'OR` condition then I am filtering out rows that are needed that are in the Outer joined table.
The issue then becomes when I use the OR criteria then the results are returning back additional rows from PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES that aren't joined to PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL (because of the LEFT OUTER JOIN and within the date range). How can I handle this situation?
(
    SELECT
        'LINE_UPDATE' UPDATE_TYPE,
        LN.PO_HEADER_ID ,
        LN.PO_LINE_ID,
        LN.LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
        LN.UNIT_PRICE,
        LN.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM,
        LN.UOM_CODE,
        ATTR.MANUFACTURER_PART_NUM,
        TLP.MANUFACTURER,
        LN_OLD.LAST_UPDATE_DATE LN_OLD_LAST_UPDATE_DT, 
        ETP.TP_ITEM_NUMBER OLD_MFG_PART,
        LN_OLD.MANUFACTURER OLD_MFG,
        LN_OLD.VENDOR_PRODUCT_NUM OLD_VENDOR_ITEM, 
        LN_OLD.UNIT_PRICE OLD_UNIT_PRICE,
        LN_OLD.UOM_CODE OLD_UOM_CODE,
        LN.ITEM_ID,
        ATTR.CREATION_DATE MFG_CREATION_DATE,
        ATTR.LAST_UPDATE_DATE MFG_LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    FROM
        PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN
    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EGP_SYSTEM_ITEMS ITM ON
            ITM.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = LN.ITEM_ID
            AND
            ITM.ORGANIZATION_ID = 300000010136542 --Master Org.
    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EGP_ITEM_RELATIONSHIPS_B EIR ON 
            EIR.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = LN.ITEM_ID
            AND
            EIR.ITEM_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE = 'MFG_PART_NUM'
    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EGP_TRADING_PARTNER_ITEMS ETP ON 
            ETP.TP_ITEM_ID = EIR.TP_ITEM_ID
            AND
            ETP.TP_TYPE = 'MANUFACTURER'
    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES ATTR ON
            ATTR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            ATTR.PO_LINE_ID = LN.PO_LINE_ID
            AND
            ATTR.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE - 22
            AND
            ATTR.MANUFACTURER_PART_NUM <> ETP.TP_ITEM_NUMBER

        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES_TLP TLP ON 
            TLP.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            TLP.PO_LINE_ID = LN.PO_LINE_ID
            AND
            TLP.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE - 22
    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN_OLD ON 
            LN_OLD.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            LN_OLD.PO_LINE_ID = LN.PO_LINE_ID                      
    
    WHERE
        ( LN.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE - 2 )
) --OR ATTR.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE - 2))


Your SQL had the OR commented out with a -- (which comments-out an entire line) so it's hard to tell which parentheses are meant to be commented-out or not.

Plenty of your JOIN ON criteria seem like they should be WHERE predicates rather than as an equijoin term (this won't affect the correctness of the query, but can make it easier for other people to understand the query's intent).

Is there a reason you're using LEFT OUTER JOIN for everything? None of them can be converted to INNER JOIN or moved to a CTE or inner-query?

@Dai this query is already actually is a CTE ( I just removed the outmost part of it). I was commenting out just --OR ATTR.LAST_UPDATE_DATE > SYSDATE - 2)) part.  I'm not sure how to overcome this issue though. If I don't use  the OR condition then I am not getting all the rows I expect, but when I do use it, I get the rows I expect, as well as several more (that I don't want) because of the LEFT OUTER JOIN type


results are returning back additional rows from PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES that aren't joined to PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL

They are returned because there is no condition joining PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES and PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL.
Either add this condition to JOIN. For example, like this:
...
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES ATTR ON
...
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN_OLD ON 
            LN_OLD.PO_HEADER_ID = ATTR.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            LN_OLD.PO_LINE_ID = ATTR.PO_LINE_ID

Or do outer joins in reverse order:
...
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN_OLD ON 
            LN_OLD.PO_HEADER_ID = LN.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            LN_OLD.PO_LINE_ID = LN.PO_LINE_ID     

        LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_ATTRIBUTE_VALUES ATTR ON
            ATTR.PO_HEADER_ID = LN_OLD.PO_HEADER_ID
            AND
            ATTR.PO_LINE_ID = LN_OLD.PO_LINE_ID
            AND
            ...

Or, if you just don't need rows without PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL data, then replace LEFT OUTER JOIN PO_LINES_ARCHIVE_ALL LN_OLD with INNER JOIN.
